# How to restart Meteor server from within Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

A project I've made with Meteor has a memory leak that slowly accumulates over the course of a month or two. After sinking days into finding the leak, I'm throwing in the towel in favor of just adding an auto-restart that happens once a month. Yes this is bad practice, etc.

Is there a way to simply restart from within the server's codebase? Ideally this will also trigger a refresh for connected clients (similar to regular deployment updates).

Then I assume this command could just be nested in a good old JS timeout function.

Comment: I think that simple `process.exit()` should do the job, since your app will probably run within an environment with autorestart feature anyways.

Comment: Have you tried using https://kadira.io/ to find the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer provided by apendua worked. It's a total hack, and not recommended for most cases, but great for long-term memory leaks.

Put this inside your startup script:

```
var restartFrequency = 1000 * 60 * 24; // 1 day (1000 millsec * 60 min * 24 hour)
setTimeout(function(){
  process.exit();
}, restartFrequency);
```

Comment: 1000 ms == 1 second.  your match should be `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24`  => 1s * 60 (== 1 min) * 60 (== 1 hr) * 24 (== 1 day)